# How to implement an (infinite) horizontal (Time) Picker in Android?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-custom-view, android-timepicker

I recently found a (custom) UI element in an EPG-Application, and I'm wondering how I can achieve something similar.

[image]

Basically: With this ui-element you can pick a time. It only shows full and half hours, but you can choose 5minutes intervalls while vertical swipe at the (whole) screen. If you choose a time, the application updates the UI depending on the chosen time.

This UI-Element is located at the top of a `ListView`. Vertical swipes let you scroll in the list, horizontal swipes (at the whole screen) changes the value of the time.

I want to implement something similar, but I have absolutely no idea, where to start. My main question is, **how can I implement and animate the time list** ?(let's say starting today till two days from now). Should I try to extend `ListView` for that? Or `TimePicker`? `Scrubber`?

**EDIT: (IDEA 1)**

1. Horizontal ListView with half time values and a Date (if you swipe to next day)
2. Textview at the top which calculates time on current value and offset of cell?

Comment: an infinite is simply not possible and practical... don't you think a few thousand years will do...

Comment: would be interesting to see what s on television in a thousands years!..but yeah you're right. let's say 3 days...